# How to convert a string to a boolean?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm retreiving some information from a server, and I'm getting let's say settings.notificationOn = "T" when the notifications are on, and settings.notificationOn = "F". I want to save it into a variable(notify: boolean) that is boolean.
And I want to use this variable in an ion-toggle, that will be checked true when notify is true and not checked when notify is false.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
const notify: boolean = (settings.notificationOn === "T");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
notify: boolean =  settings.notificationOn == "T" ? true : false ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that `notificationOn` has not any bad values you can do it like this:

```
const notify: boolean = this.getNotificationStatus(settings);

getNotificationStatus(settings: { notificationOn: 'T' | 'F' }): boolean {
  if (settings.notificationOn === "T") return true;
  if (settings.notificationOn === "F") return false;
  throw new Error("/* Your error here */");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string that has either 'F' or 'T' then you can use the following code:

```
const notify = settings.notificationOn === 'T';
```

Short explanation:

You are assigning to the notify variable the result from the expression of whether settings.notificationOn is equal to 'T'. If it is, value will be true, else, false.

Answer (score 0):

if "T" then true, else false.

```
const notify: boolean = settings.notificationOn === "T" ? true : false;
```